# Fabric plugin crash --> No such property: betaDistributionApkFilePath for class: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I am not able to configure Crashlytics in my application.
Just when I apply the fabric plugin (`plugin: 'io.fabric'`) and build, I get this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: betaDistributionApkFilePath for class: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 4s
No such property: betaDistributionApkFilePath for class: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
```

My gradle files are :

*build.gradle* (project level)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*build.gradle* (app level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply from: '../dependencies.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion compileVersion
    buildToolsVersion = buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId appId
        minSdkVersion minVersion
        targetSdkVersion targetVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(keyStoreFile)
            keyPassword releaseKeyPassword
            keyAlias releaseKeyAlias
            storePassword releaseStorePassword
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('../extra/debug.jks')
            keyPassword 'android'
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'android'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_release"
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://www.mywebsite.com/api/"'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            shrinkResources false
            multiDexEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_debug"
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://staging.mywebsite.com/api/"'
        }
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation testDependencies.values()
    testImplementation androidTestDependencies.values()

    implementation kotlinDependencies.values()
    implementation androidSupportLibraries.values()
    implementation daggerDependencies.values()
    implementation androidArchDependencies.values()
    implementation rxJavaDependencies.values()
    implementation retrofitDependencies.values()
    implementation firebaseDependencies.values()
    implementation cookieJar
    implementation timber
    implementation crashlytics

    implementation glide
    api glideDependencies.values()
    kapt glideCompiler

    kapt daggerAnnotationProcessor.values()
    kapt roomAnnotationProcessor
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

*dependencies.gradle* (all dependencies declared over here)

```
ext {

    compileVersion = 28
    minVersion = 16
    targetVersion = 28
    buildTools = '28.0.3'

    appId = 'com.mywebsite.demo'

    def kotlinVersion = '1.3.41'
    def kotlinCoreVersion = '1.0.2'
    def daggerVersion = '2.17'
    def retrofitVersion = '2.4.0'
    def loggingInterceptorVersion = '3.10.0'
    def rxAndroidVersion = '2.1.1'
    def rxJavaVersion = '2.2.9'
    def testRunnerVersion = '1.1.1'
    def appCompatVersion = '1.0.2'
    def espressoCoreVersion = '3.1.1'
    def constraintLayoutVersion = '1.1.3'
    def lifecycleExtensionsVersion = '1.1.1'
    def cookieJarVersion = "v1.0.1"
    def roomVersion = "2.1.0-rc01"
    def roomRxVersion = "1.1.1"
    def roomAnnotationProcessorVersion = "2.0.0-rc01"
    def timberVersion = "4.6.1"
    def recyclerViewVersion = "1.0.0"
    def designSupportLibVersion = "1.1.0-alpha06"
    def glideVersion = "4.9.0"
    def glideTransformationVersion = "3.0.1"
    def firebaseAnalyticsVersion = "17.0.1"
    def firebaseConfigVersion = "18.0.0"
    def fcmVersion = "19.0.1"
    def crashlyticsVersion = "2.10.1"

    testDependencies = [
            "junit": "junit:junit:4.13-beta-3"
    ]

    androidTestDependencies = [
            "runner"      : "androidx.test:runner:$testRunnerVersion",
            "espressoCore": "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoCoreVersion"
    ]

    kotlinDependencies = [
            "kotlinStdLib": "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion",
            "kotlinCore"  : "androidx.core:core-ktx:$kotlinCoreVersion"
    ]

    androidSupportLibraries = [
            "appcompat"       : "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion",
            "constraintlayout": "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintLayoutVersion",
            "recyclerview"    : "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerViewVersion",
            "design"          : "com.google.android.material:material:$designSupportLibVersion",

    ]

    retrofitDependencies = [
            "retrofit"           : "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion",
            "gson"               : "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion",
            "adapter-rxjava2"    : "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion",
            "logging-interceptor": "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$loggingInterceptorVersion"
    ]

    rxJavaDependencies = [
            "rxandroid": "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion",
            "rxjava"   : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    ]

    androidArchDependencies = [
            "lifecycleExtensions": "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycleExtensionsVersion",
            "room"               : "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion",
            "roomRx"             : "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$roomRxVersion"
    ]

    daggerAnnotationProcessor = [
            "daggerCompiler": "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion",
            "daggerAP"      : "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
    ]

    daggerDependencies = [
            "dagger"                : "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion",
            "dagger-android"        : "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion",
            "dagger-android-support": "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
    ]

    glideDependencies = [
            "glideIntegration"        : "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:$glideVersion",
            "glideAnnotationProcesser": "com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:$glideVersion",
            "glideTransformation"     : "jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:${glideTransformationVersion}",
    ]

    firebaseDependencies = [
            "firebaseAnalytics": "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseAnalyticsVersion",
            "firebaseConfig"   : "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$firebaseConfigVersion",
            "fcm"              : "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${fcmVersion}"
    ]

    cookieJar = "com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:$cookieJarVersion"
    roomAnnotationProcessor = "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomAnnotationProcessorVersion"
    timber = "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${timberVersion}"
    glide = "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${glideVersion}"
    glideCompiler = "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:${glideVersion}"
    crashlytics = "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${crashlyticsVersion}"

}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.mywebsite.demo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:name=".App"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.mywebsite.demo.app.activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
                android:name=".managers.fcm.FcmMessageService"
                android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
                android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
                android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved by doing a lot of hit and trial on how `Crashlytics` needs to be declared in separate Gradle file.

Changes made were :
*dependencies.gradle*

```
Before

ext {
    def crashlyticsVersion = "2.10.1"
    crashlytics = "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${crashlyticsVersion}"
}

After

ext {
    def crashlyticsVersion = "2.10.1"
    crashlyticsDependencies = [
            "crashlytics": "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${crashlyticsVersion}"
    ]
}
```

*build.gradle* (app level)

```
Before

dependencies {
    implementation crashlytics
}

After

dependencies {
    implementation crashlyticsDependencies.values()
}
```

Still not sure why crashlytics forces only this type of declaration.